# Python. Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: python, кодировка, перекодировка

Как расшифровать такую строку:

```
РїР° 
РІ
РїРї
Р°РІ
Рї Рї
```

в python?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, у вас проблема с локализацией или у вас вопрос по шифрованию?

Comment: @0xdb По количеству "Р" должно быть понятно. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.

```
urllib.parse.unquote(content).encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: поправьте ваш вопрос, чтобы прийти к вашему ответу можно было бы без чтения мыслей, чтобы он мог помочь ещё кому-нибудь. Откуда content взялся? какое отношение к данным в вопросе он имеет? `unquote()` принимает percent-encoding содержимое. Данный в вопросе не являются urlencoded. Данные в вопросе выглядят как будто utf-8 данные были с помощью cp1251 кодировки декодированы. Какой код у вас это сделал? `open()`? https://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/